# Getting non equals values from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a nested dictionary like that

```
my_dict =  {

'ae15': {'selector1fpc0': {'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'},
          'selector1fpc1': {'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'},
          'selector1fpc10': {'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'},
          'selector1fpc4': {'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'},
          'selector1fpc5': {'12': ' de80451ee5a9e5d69f243a42f1e72d1f'},
          'selector1fpc7': {'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'},
          'selector1fpc8': {'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'},
          'selector1fpc9': {'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'}},
 'ae16': {'selector1fpc0': {'7': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'},
          'selector1fpc1': {'7': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'},
          'selector1fpc10': {'8': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'},
          'selector1fpc4': {'7': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'},
          'selector1fpc5': {'7': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'},
          'selector1fpc7': {'7': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'},
          'selector1fpc8': {'7': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'},
          'selector1fpc9': {'7': ' 119a58e92e581d90eba9a57262d297e5'}}}
```

and I want to check if all internal values of the dict are equals

i.e

in ae15 selector1fpc5 value is different from the rest however in ae16 all the values are identical

I'm trying the following code

```
for k, dic in my_dict.items():
    print(dic.values())
    iterable = iter(dic.values())
    first = next(iterable)
    all_equals = all(first == val for val in iterable for k in dic.keys())
    print(k,all_equals)
```

however I'm getting False in both cases, when actually only ae195 has a different value.

Comment: Are you looking to compare the int key and str value, or just the str value? i.e. if you had ```{'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'}```, are you just looking for the value ```'3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'``` or ```{'12': ' 3b1874ee5465656256079d02a301acf5'}```.

Comment: If it's the later, then in ```ae16``` on of the keys is ```8``` when the others are all ```7``` therefore the ```all(first == val for val in iterable for k in dic.keys())``` will return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest one level deeper at a different place:

```
from itertools import chain

for k, dic in my_dict.items():
    iterable = chain(*(d.values() for d in dic.values())) # to here  ...
    first = next(iterable)
    all_equals = all(first == val for val in iterable)  # ... from here!
    print(k, all_equals)

ae15 False
ae16 True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine !